# Does Dead Store Elimination work on class member variables in the Destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, memset

I'm aware that DSE is a [problem](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/14.html) for crypto developers who primarily use C, particularly with the reliance on `memset`. However, would the same be true if a class zeroes out its member variables within the destructor? Does DSE work on destructors? Do the various C++ versions treat this differently?

Comment: C++ has the as-if rule.  So, as long as removing the zeroing doesn't change how the program works, an optimizer is allowed to remove it.

Comment: And I don't see any reason that a destructor should be handled differently from other functions by the optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I was unsure about this.

Comment: To add a bit to the comment by @NathanOliver, the as-if rule is about **observable side effects**. Zeroing memory that's about to be recycled doesn't have any side effects that can be seen by a valid C++ program, so the compiler is free to skip it.

Comment: Also, I would expect it to work _especially well_ in destructors, since the compiler can assume all those variables are dead as soon as the function returns without further analysis.